# Combining multiple return statements in one factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am currently diving into the  AngularJS layers and I want to know how (I know it is possible) to combine my two factory modules:

```
// one
services.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
            {
                authenticate: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {'action': 'authenticate'},
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                },
            });
});

//two
services.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('rest/user/:id', {id: '@id'});
});
```

I have tried this:

```
services.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {

    return {
        authenticateUser: $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
                {
                    authenticate: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        params: {'action': 'authenticate'},
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    },
                }),
        userID: $resource('rest/user/:id', {id: '@id'})
    };

});
```

and with function variables. I am using one RESTful Web Service for all the actions for a user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

change them to method

```
services.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {

    return {
        authenticateUser: function() {
            return $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
                {
                    authenticate: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        params: {'action': 'authenticate'},
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    },
                })
        },
        userID: function () {
            return $resource('rest/user/:id', {id: '@id'})
        }
    };

});
```

and use them as

```
// authenticate user
var UserAuth = UserService.authenticateUser();
UserAuth.authenticate({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password});

// user id
var UserId = UserService.userID();
UserId.get({id: 123}, function (user) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: I used to use it like this:  UserService.authenticate($.param({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}), function (authenticationResult) { // code. So now I just add UserService.authenticateUser().authenticate($.param ..etc.. ?